# Restricting An IPad or tablet

Tags: android, ios, jailbreak, uber-api, ubertesters

I am wondering how a company like uber customizes their iPhones so that they can only use the uber app. Is this a technology, service, or type of jailbreak?

Comment: On iOS you use the Apple Configurator tool to lock the device into single app mode

Answer (score 0):

They must be using an MDM solution (mobile device management). This allows them to remotely manage their mobile devices. One of the features provided by MDM is single app mode, which enables you to lock a device to one app.